# Calculate Employee Experience from Multiple Jobs

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, predicate, specifications

I have a table named employee experience with id, userId, startDate, endDate columns.

I want to calculate employee experience. Can someone please help with mysql query or JPA specification code?

For example in case of following data:

| id | userID | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2019-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2021-01-01 |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |

the output should be:

| userID | experience |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: 'calculate employee experience; - I don't know what you mean by this. Please add sample data , expected output and what you have so far as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon updated.

Comment: Still don't know what experience is ? is it years or roles?

Answer (score 0):

Successfully did this with the following:

```sql
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, START_DATE, END_DATE)) AS experience,
          SOCIAL_PROFILE_ID
   FROM tableName
   GROUP BY SOCIAL_PROFILE_ID
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).